# Package morewrites kills tikz's opacity/transparancy

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency, write-file

I made the strange observation that including the `morewrites` package removes opacity colours in `tikzpicture`.

[image: The picture with transparancy ie. morewrites commented out]
[image: The same picture w/o transparency ie. morewrites included]

(The code of this example is given below.)

As opacity problems with `tikz` package are reported several times across this forum, it is quite possible that in such cases packages like `morewrites` is the clue. Only to let you know. There are probably others out there more capable of debugging this problem.

As an alternative I tried the `scrwfile` packages. It produced transparancy properly but failed with more writes.

```
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage[tikz]{mdframed}
 %\usepackage{morewrites}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{figure}[!htb]
  \definecolor{c979797}{RGB}{151,151,151}
  \definecolor{cc7c7c7}{RGB}{199,199,199}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.60pt,x=0.60pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
   \path[fill=c979797,rounded corners=0.0000cm] (214.2360,457.9447) rectangle
(231.4793,632.2944);
   \path[draw=black,fill=c979797,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.813pt]
(673.2180,582.0061) .. controls (628.0447,595.2757) and (673.7736,582.0221) ..
(628.0573,595.2501) .. controls (589.7109,585.1109) and (587.9273,578.9819) ..
(630.7735,569.0304) .. controls (671.3900,581.4329) and (630.7730,568.9839) ..
(673.2180,582.0061) -- cycle;
   \path[draw=black,fill=cc7c7c7,opacity=0.514,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.813pt]
(100.2528,568.7324) .. controls (100.2528,568.7324) and (602.8691,568.7324) ..
(628.2308,568.7324) .. controls (645.7917,568.7324) and (611.0254,595.2799) ..
(628.2308,595.2799) .. controls (645.4363,595.2799) and (100.2528,595.2799) ..
(100.2528,595.2799) -- cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) demonstrating the behaviour.

Comment: Without an example we can't say much. But did you try reversing the order of the package declarations. I guess this is an `atbegshi` issue in disguise. I'm really curious how you managed to ran out of `\write`s

Comment: With your example I have no problems in both cases (commented and uncommented)

Comment: That's strange. It draws the picture in both cases without problems. However only if commented I get transparant colours? I'd like to upload the pictures.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a non-reproducible problem.